# Powering device through external power supply, programming via PC USB

Tags: power-supply, fpga, short-circuit

Would really appreciate some help with this:

I have a set up for a project which has worked fine for a while. I have a 5V bench power supply that is powering an FPGA development board and the rest of the electronics (a rotary encoder opto-coupler circuit). The FPGA board became damaged as I mistakenly plugged the negative connection from the power supply into the 24V channel that feeds another part of the electronics for the project. This a dual channel power supply with the 5V and 24V channel negatives tied together. The negatives are not tied to ground.

To program the FPGA, it's USB port is plugged into my PC USB port. Before the FPGA was damaged, I was able to power the FPGA with the 5V power supply, and have the USB cable plugged into the PC.

Now that I have replaced the FPGA, when I plug in the USB cable into the FPGA, the FPGA power supply shuts down. Why is this doing this and why did it not do it before?

Also, should you always ground the negative of the power supply?

The FPGA is a Nexys A7-100T.

The power supply is an RS3305P.

Comment: *Why is this doing this and why did it not do it before* - You have fried some other stuff except the FPGA.

Comment: @EugeneSh. But the other devices are powered up and there is no issue until I plug the USB cable in from PC to FPGA.

Comment: Then something in the USB circuitry is broken

Comment: @EugeneSh. On the PC side you mean?

Comment: On either side. If the same USB port on the PC is working for other devices, then PC is fine.

Comment: @EugeneSh. USB ports that happily run a USB stick, keyboard and another MCU, still won't run the FPGA. I will replace some other hardware and see if it fixes it.

Comment: @David777 Under the circumstances that a board is powered by lab supply and has connections to other equipment like grounded/earthed PC, I would never ground/earth the lab supply negative lead, I would keep it floating. The reason is that if the negative supply lead disconnects from any reason, current would still flow from lab supply via mains ground/earth wiring to PC and from PC via USB negative to board. If the current is large it may damage earth wiring, PC, USB cable, etc anything in the loop that is not meant for amps of lab PSU currents to flow.

Comment: @EugeneSh. It turned out to be another device that was faulty. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Justme Ok, that is what I needed to hear. I think this is how I blew the first FPGA as I had the negative tied to the mains earth. I was having trouble reading the correct with a serial ADC output from a chip. When the oscilloscope was connected to the signals, the output was nearly perfect, and without the oscilloscope connected, the serial data was garbage. I then thought it seemed like a grounding problem, hence grounding the negative of bench PSU.